# Use a module inside of a module in Rust

Tags: module, rust

I have a file *Projectile.rs* that is in the `src` directory. It is currently used by *main.rs*. However, I require the file *FreeFall.rs* sharing the same directory to be used in *Projectile.rs*. Here is how it looks at the moment:

**DIRECTORY**

```
src
 |___main.rs
 |___Projectile.rs
 |___FreeFall.rs
```

**MAIN.RS**

```
mod Projectile;
fn main() {
    println!("Goed... momenteel");
    Projectile::projectile(10.0, 5.0, 100.0, 7.5);
}
```

**PROJECTILE.RS**

```
use std;
mod FreeFall;
pub fn projectile(init: f64, AngleX: f64, AngleY: f64, AngleZ: f64) {
    let mut FFAccel = FreeFall::acceleration();
    struct Velocities {
        x: f64,
        y: f64,
        z: f64,
        t: f64,
    };
    let mut Object1 = Velocities {
        x: init * AngleX.sin(),
        y: init * AngleY.cos(),
        z: init * AngleZ.tan(),
        t: (2.0 * init.powf(-1.0) * AngleY.sin()) / FFAccel,
    };
    println!("{}", Object1.t);
}
```

**FREEFALL.RS**

```
use std;

pub fn acceleration() {
    // maths here
}
```

I can't just use the value 9.81 (which is the average gravity on Earth) because it does not take into account air resistance, terminal velocity, etc.

I tried including the `FreeFall` module into *main.rs* instead, but it did not work.

Comment: You need to move `freefall.rs` into a subdirectory called `projectile`. Also note that `use std;` doesn't do anything, and that rust module names are lower case by convention.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: You should make an effort not to confuse *files* with *modules*. Files may contain multiple modules (but modules may not be spread across multiple files, as in some other languages). You could, for example, put the contents of `freefall.rs` directly within `mod freefall { /* here */ }`, and not have to create a new file.

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `projectile`; `free_fall` instead, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rust, single-file modules can't declare other modules from other files with the `mod` keyword. To do this, you need to create a directory for the module, name the module root file `mod.rs`, and create a separate file (or directory) inside that one for each nested module.

As a rule of thumb, you should declare every module in the "root file" (typically `main.rs`, `lib.rs` or `mod.rs`) of the directory, and `use` it everywhere else. Conveniently, you can use `crate::` as the root module of your crate, and refer to your modules using that.

---

For example:

```
src/
  main.rs             crate
  foo.rs              crate::foo
  bar.rs              crate::bar
  baz/
    mod.rs            crate::baz
    inner.rs          crate::baz::inner
```

**main.rs**

```
// declare the modules---we only do this once in our entire crate
pub mod foo;
pub mod bar;
pub mod baz;

fn main() { }
```

**foo.rs**

```
// use other modules in this crate
use crate::bar::*;
use crate::baz::inner::*;
```

**baz/mod.rs**

```
// the baz module contains a nested module,
// which has to be declared here
pub mod inner;
```

---

Some resources for further reading:

- [The Module System to Control Scope and Privacy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html)
- [Rust modules explained](https://medium.com/@tak2siva/rust-modules-explained-96809931bbbf)

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that I had to do it in that way.